# Draft Deployment: Remove "Okay. Let's get the test version of X"

Tags: actions-on-google

Is there any way to remove that initial "welcome" voice message like "Okay. Let's get the test version of XX" when an action is pushed via "Draft"(!) mode?

I have coded a small action, which is only useful for myself and don't want (and probably google won't allow) to publish this to the world.

Answer (score 2):

No. The question comes up fairly frequently on the Google+ support page but essentially it boils down to this - there are test apps and public published apps. If you want to make an app and deploy privately your only option is to use authentication.

That said, if you give your Action a name then you can invoke it by speaking its name into the microphone on a device (phone, Home etc) or the simulator. That will remove the annoying "my test app" bit, but you'll still hear "the test version" quip before activation.

Finally, you can allow others to use the app if you mark them as "testers" in the Actions console.

Comment: Thanks. Because it is stupid to hear the "my test app" bit every time, the solution would be to publish this action. Will google accept the action even when it is only useful for me?

Comment: I don't speak for them but their policy is here - https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies . My expectation is that if you don't violate any of the terms there and if your action is in concordance with the checklist that pops up when you click "publish" in the Actions console then I would guess that they would.

Comment: @Tobias Did you ever manage to publish the app? I'm trying to do something similar for a personal project

Comment: @DirkV No, i stopped trying and migrated to AWS, which worked without any issues.

Comment: @Tobias After a long search I finally figured out how to do it. I put it in the reply above here

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it. Without needing an app review.

1. Go back to the deploy tab -> release. And click on "manage alpha testers" on the upper right. Then in the list add your own email address.
2. Go to the deploy tab of the google action console -> release. And release your app as an Alpha version. ( alpha versions won't be checked to it will be released directly)
3. Go to the Test tab of the action console and click on the settings icon in the upper right. In the settings disable "On device testing option".
4. Back on the deploy -> release page, go to "manage alpha testers" and click on the Opt-in page link. And you will have added the alpha version to your google home.

Now you are using the Alpha version on the device that does not have the "getting test version of X" message!